# Listening to EVERY port on a machine

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, port

For testing purposes I want to build a server that listens for TCP connections to every port (or at least on most of the ports) on a certain interface (e.g., eth0). The server is accessed via SSH to eth1, so no problem there. (I do not care about UDP or other protocols)

I want to do a special kind of middlebox detection/analysis, therefore I need to be able to fully establish a connection. Having an HTTP connection would be the best, because the "client" could be implemented as JS in the Browser.

I started with a simple jetty server, but had to realize that jetty needs to spawn at least on thread per port it is listening to. This leads to problems when I want to listen to several thousand ports. **Or is there a way around that?**

My next try was to use `iptables`:

> sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:8080`

It seemed to work. It allows to connect on every port and the traffic gets routed to the local port 8080 where jetty listens. But now I no longer know which port was used by the client. Because jetty thinks the connection was established via port 8080. **Is there a way to determine the real incomming port from jetty?** I could send the port as part of the HTTP request, but if the client tries to contact port 1234 .. and a middlebox redirects this to port 5678 .. I am unable to know what port was used.

I also tried userland solutions like `socat`. The problem was even worse than before. Because now jetty also saw the remote IP as being 127.0.0.1.

**Or, is there another way to achieve this?**

Oh and btw: I have full control of the machine. So I could change the kernel or whatever is needed. Right now I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, but if a solution needs something else I could go with that.

Comment: I think this may be offtopic for Stack Overflow. Have you considered using `inetd` to attach a script to ports?

Comment: I was also unsure if I should try superuser instead of stackoverflow. But usually stackoverflow attracts more expers. I have not tried `inetd`, I will have a look at it.

Comment: wireshark is passive. I need to be able to establish the connection with the full TCP handshake, etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**NB**: This is a Python solution, because I know Python, but you can accomplish the same thing in any language the exposes the underlying C library `getsockopt` call.

If you replace your `DNAT` rule with a `REDIRECT` rule, you can then
use `getsockopt` with the `SO_ORIGINAL_DST` option to retrieve the
original address of a `REDIRECT`-ed connection.

Consider the following code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket
import struct

SO_ORIGINAL_DST = 80

s = socket.socket()
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind(('0.0.0.0', 2000))
s.listen(10)

while True:
    csock, caddr = s.accept()
    orig_dst = csock.getsockopt(socket.SOL_IP, SO_ORIGINAL_DST, 16)
    
    orig_port = struct.unpack('>H', orig_dst[2:4])
    orig_addr = socket.inet_ntoa(orig_dst[4:8])

    print 'connection from', caddr
    print 'connection to', (orig_addr, orig_port)
    print
```

If I have an iptables rule that looks like:

```
# iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 1500:1600 \
  -j REDIRECT --to-port 2000
```

And while the above Python code is running I connect *from another
host* to `my_ip_address:1500`, I see:

```
connection from ('192.168.1.20', 35790)
connection to ('192.168.1.75', (1500,))
```

And if I connect to port 1550 I see:

```
connection from ('192.168.1.20', 42054)
connection to ('192.168.1.75', (1550,))
```

Which I think is exactly what you were asking for.  Note that to my knowledge this will only work for TCP connections; there are other solutions (possibly involving the `TPROXY` iptables target) that may work with UDP connections as well.

Comment: Oh this works great. Now I only need to find out how to access getsockopt from java .. or how to adapt my server to something like python or C/C++ .. but this is doable.

Comment: If you're happy with this answer, consider clicking on the checkmark to the left of the answer.  This is both a way of saying "thanks" and also a way of letting folks know that your question has been answered.